# How to add a highlighted area within the scatter with straight lines graph

Tags: excel, graph, charts

When I try to change the graph to combo and make it area it gets messed up, and doesn't follow the coordinates.

As you could see this is before changing it to area which is allign with my coordinates:
[before changing the scatter line with straight line to area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxpqw.png)

but when I change it to stacked area or normal area it changes the coordinates:
[after change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muoVs.png)

This is the graph i'm trying to make:
[graph example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQoAp.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.